# "Initial" vs "Eventual" validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation

In general, can we consider an HTML document that is initially invalid but *eventually* becomes technically valid (through scripting) to be OK?

"OK" would be per good practices, or possibly with regard to the standard, if it answers this question.

For example, the document that results from parsing this serialized HTML markup validates initially using the [W3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>foo</title>
bar
```

While this one doesn't:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>document.title = 'foo'</script>
bar
```

And that is even though the result is exactly the same for any browser that supports Javascript.  Assuming this is a web application and JS is required, is this kind of thing "OK"?

I especially wonder about this situation when we *don't* have any correct (from an application perspective) way of satisfying the standard initially.  For example, what if we don't know the title of the document initially, and must compute/retrieve it using a script?

In this particular case, using a placeholder feels wrong:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>placeholder</title>
<script>document.title = 'foo'</script>
bar
```

(Note that leaving the title element empty is still considered invalid.)

So, without debating too much about the title element in particular, is it *generally* accepted to distribute HTML resources that are only *eventually* valid?

*Subquestion:  I realize that validating the document (as represented by the DOM) and validating its serialized markup are two different things;  are there any tools to do the former?  (Either from a snapshot of the DOM or "continuously".)  Example:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>foo</title>
<script>document.title = ''</script>
bar
```

*This validates initially but technically results in an invalid document, without any obvious way to detect it.*

**Update:** Obviously such a tool would have limited value in a static analysis context (halting problem, etc).  A runtime tool should be useful however.

**Update:** [W3C spec for DOM validation (Level 3)](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Val/).

**Update:** [W3C spec for Service Workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/), which seems like it could be used to ensure a DOM is valid before being rendered, even if the template is not (avoiding the use of placeholder elements and such).  It's still early at the time of this writing (June 26th 2014, so don't quote me on that).

Comment: As this heavily depends on how validity is defined, what is the practical reason for asking? That should help to decide which definition of validity should be applied.

Comment: You're right; I define it here as the document (as represented by the DOM) being valid per the HTML standard, not the markup representation. Originally, I wanted to avoid the equivalent of [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) for JS-generated content and decided that this was a more straightforward question that I had to answer first. Admittedly, most problems often come from not-exactly-sane template frameworks, and `title` might turn out to be quite unique. It turns out that what I really want is to run code before rendering, which is currently impossible AFAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An invalid HTML document is **not** ok, even if you make it valid with scripts for various reasons.

HTML documents are validated and parsed as it's loading, before scripts are being run. So even if you "fix" your document with scripts, there's a high probability your document will be funky. Even if you generate all content in a script, a lot of browsers will not accept.

Besides, if you care about search engines, please remember that:

- Search engines consider invalid HTML a bad thing and will affect your ranking
- Scripts are not evaluated or parsed whatsoever, your HTML document will remain invalid

Last but not least, don't forget the small amount of clients that have scripts disabled.

Comment: Googlebot actually does process JavaScript. I'm sure some others do too, due to the large amount of AJAX-powered sites.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Did it in 2010? I know they do now, but it's still unclear to what extend. But it's still a bad practise to write invalid HTML because that's still parsed on page-load :)

Comment: Ah, right, sorry! Saw this show up in "recent activity" because of the edit, and didn't pay attention XD

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, Tim S.: The question was asked and answered on Sep 10 '13, not '10, so I guess there's nothing wrong with this comment. By the way, it's a bit unfortunate that I didn't emphasize the corollary: that we should still care to deal with eventual validation during dev because initially valid documents may become invalid through scripting. The DOM-Level-3-Val (see update) answers this, though I have yet to discover good tools that implement it. I tried to convince myself about initial validation, but the title example still bothers me: for instance, what if the title is localized?

Answer (score 0):

i don't see how you want to decide whether a document '*eventually* becomes technically valid'. scripting code may refer to arbitrary contextual state (existing dom, user client info, localstorage, user input, web request responses url). most of this info is inaccessible beforehand to the validator.

your scheme might work with a very restricted subset of scripting instructions but i can't see how that could be of any use in real life applications.

so, no, i don't think that the concept of eventual validation is sound. documents that do not validate intially shouldn't be considered ok.

Comment: You're right for any static analyzer, I was probably looking more for a runtime tool that one would use when running tests (for example). I probably should have made that distinction.